# Localhost testing stopped working - what changed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, localhost

I am developing FB app using FB JS SDK and Flask.
The last time I checked my app on localhost testing was a week before the end of Semptember, and then everything worked fine.

I got back to my app today and I got this:

```
Curses! Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: 
One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  
It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be 
a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

I had the configuration working two weeks ago so what has changed really?

Code:

```
function fbLogin(handle)
{
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

if (DEBUG) console.log("start login");

FB.init({
  appId : XXXXXXXXXX,//app_id,// App ID
  //channelUrl : channel_url, // Channel File 
  channelUrl : '//127.0.0.1:5000/channel.html', // Channel File 
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});

if (DEBUG) console.log("login status");

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) 
{
    if (DEBUG) console.log("get login status"); 
    if (DEBUG) console.log(response);

    if (response.status == 'connected') {
        if (DEBUG) console.log("connecto!");
        getUser(handle);
        getFriends();
    } 
    else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
    {
        if (DEBUG) console.log("not auth");   
        fbLoginAPI();
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (DEBUG) console.log("not logged!");   
        fbLoginAPI();
    }
}, true);   


};

(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
 }(document));
}
```

Site URL: http: //127.0.0.1:5000/
Canvas URL: http: //127.0.0.1:5000/

I can't set the secure url https: //127.0.0.1:5000/ as it gives me:

```
Misfire
Secure Canvas URL cannot be a Facebook URL.
```

I tried starting my app with foreman with and without SSL and it still does not work.

Comment: Are you trying the app in the facebook? Or localhost?

Comment: Localhost as it stands in the topic.

Comment: then try `localhost` in the site url

Comment: You mean like http ://localhost:5000 ?
Tried that, it did not change a thing.